# Cropped icon with native base button

Tags: react-native, button, icons, native-base

I'm using native base to create round icon buttons.
When the icon is small it works fine :

```
<Button   
    rounded 
    style={{
        borderRadius : 32,
        width : 64,
        height : 64,

    }} 
>
    <Icon  
        name="bell"
        type="MaterialCommunityIcons"
        style={{
            fontSize: 35, 
            marginLeft : 14
        }}
    />
</Button>
```

[image: Icon works fine]
When I change the icon size, it becomes cropped

```
<Button   
    rounded 
    style={{
        borderRadius : 32,
        width : 64,
        height : 64,

    }} 
>
    <Icon  
        name="bell"
        type="MaterialCommunityIcons"
        style={{
            fontSize: 60, //bigger icon
            marginLeft : 3
        }}
    />
</Button>
```

[image: Icon is cropped]
What should I do to display the icon over the button?
EDIT : 
The problem gets worse as the button becomes smaller (the vertical cropping line gets closer to the button's center)

Comment: i think you should also make the background circle bigger if you want to make the icon bigger. For example make the width and height of the <Button> Component 72x72

Comment: Your icon is cropped because the button overflow is hidden. Give absolute position to the icon

Comment: Setting Icon position to absolute makes the button unclickable

Comment: i got same error fixed by giving small fontSize in Icon style, but this was not proper